# Django: Builtin Views and Forms throwing "object has no attribute 'users_cache'"

Tags: python, django, forms

Attempting to use the built in auth.views and auth.form for password reset.

Have the following in `forms.py`:

```
class CustomPasswordResetForm(PasswordResetForm):
    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
    if email and 'gmail.com' in email:
        raise forms.ValidationError(u'Unfortunately, we can not reset Gmail usernames')
    return email
```

And the following in `urls.py`:

```
url(r'^passreset/$', auth_views.password_reset, {'template_name': 'registration/password_reset.html', 'password_reset_form': CustomPasswordResetForm}),
```

If I type an email like `sample@gmail.com`, it properly throws the validation error. However, if I type a non-gmail email, it validates whether its a proper email address in the superclass, BUT it doesn't validate whether there is a user associated with that email, and instead returns:

```
AttributeError at /passreset/
'CustomPasswordResetForm' object has no attribute 'users_cache'
```

Any ideas? I'm not sure where to start, and a Google search didn't really turn up much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem. I had forgotten to call the original method in the super class once I had overridden clean_email. Changing the 3rd line to the below solves the problem.

```
email = super(CustomPasswordResetForm, self).clean_email()
```